# Alfresco - set permisson for assignee in workflow

Tags: alfresco

I need set permission to read (consumer) for assignee user in workflow for all items in current taks.
So, when user get task in workflow with item on which he hasn't have permission before, he will get permission to read for all package items. He have to know what is he accepting...

I'm wondering what is best approach.

1. I can create Task listener on create event and set permission there. But then I need set this listener to every task in all workflows (that's a lot of places).
2. I think i can create some behavior to manage this, but don't know on what event and class to run it. And I'm scared of dependency to performance.
3. I can override PermissionServiceImpl but that is terrible idea from my point of view. I don't wanna override Alfresco core.

Or is some other solution?

I work with Alfresco 7.4 CE.